# Disable sheet name when selecting from active sheet - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When you write a formula in excel and you select a cell in a different worksheet to the one in which you are writing the formula, the sheet name appears in the formula.  This makes sense, it wouldn't work without it.  When you write a formulae in excel and you select a cell in a different worksheet to the one in which you are writing the formula then select another cell in the active worksheet, it also adds in the sheet name for the active worksheet.  Is there a way to stop this happening?

E.g. if you're writing a formula in Sheet1, I want my formula to read:

=sum(Sheet2!A1 + A1)

NOT

=sum(Sheet2!A1 + Sheet1!A1)

I understand that I can do this manually but it's very time consuming!

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything. At the end you could remove them all using Find and Replace perhaps.

Comment: ^^ Which is also not time-consuming =)

Comment: Lol!  Yup...could do that, but time consuming.  I feel that there must be an option in VBA somewhere to turn it on/off but I couldn't find/work it out.

Comment: Hardly time consuming, you can do it one go.

Comment: That's assuming that you don't need to refresh and check and that you're doing it for a single sheet... both of which are not true.  I'm sorry but your solution is not really viable, though I appreciate the input.

Comment: You haven't tagged your question with VBA but obviously it could be done that way for any number of sheets.

Comment: Then you can still apply this method in a `For` loop where you'd replace each sheetname in the formulas. I don't think you can stop this mechanic through settings though.

Comment: I know I can fix it with VBA but I don't want to have to fix it... but fine, thanks for the info, was hoping there might be a setting or a VBA command I could use that would prevent it from happening at all.